# Can I use the andFilterWhere([]) to search for all value that start with?

Tags: yii2

I am using the yii2 framework and GridView and just learning yii2

Can I use the andFilterWhere([]) to search for all values that start with? a specific value similar to SQL where you can use zip%  or is there some function better to use.

I want to search for a zipcode in a database that starts with the the number I entered.

I originally used

```
->andFilterWhere(['like', 'zip', $this->zip])
```

but that searches any possible combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. It's done like that by passing `false` as 4th array element:

```
['like', 'zip', 'zip%', false],
```

Or if it depends on model attribute value:

```
['like', 'zip', $this->zip . '%', false],
```

Please read more about building where section of query [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where%28%29-detail), there is example about this case:

> `like`: operand 1 should be a column or DB expression, and operand 2
>   be a string or an array representing the values that the column or DB
>   expression should be like. For example, `['like', 'name', 'tester']`
>   will generate `name LIKE '%tester%'`. When the value range is given as
>   an array, multiple LIKE predicates will be generated and concatenated
>   using `AND`. For example, `['like', 'name', ['test', 'sample']]` will
>   generate name `LIKE '%test%' AND name LIKE '%sample%'`. The method
>   will properly quote the column name and escape special characters in
>   the values. Sometimes, you may want to add the percentage characters
>   to the matching value by yourself, you may supply a third operand
>   false to do so. For example, `['like', 'name', '%tester', false]` will
>   generate `name LIKE '%tester'`.

Answer (score 1):

Try andFilterWhere as :-

```
->andFilterWhere(['like', 'zip', $this->zip.'%' ,false]);
```

it will create query `where zip like 'zipcode%'`